# Shared docker volume mounts host directory

Tags: docker-volume

I like to mount a specific directory on my host machine an two containers. Everything is defined in a docker-compose.yaml file.

In the services section of the yaml file, for both containers, the following is specified:

```
volumes:
- myvolume:/internal/path
```

In the volume section, the volume is defined as:

```
volumes:
    myvolume:
        driver: local
```

The shared volume is located in /var/libs/docker/volumes as a single file by default. Now, I want to specify a directory in the host's file system, let's say directory /host/directory. Can somebody please state how to realize that by means of docker-compose?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing host volumes with docker services is done by specifying the volume in the service section like this:

```
# ...
    volumes:
      - /path/in/host:/path/in/service
# ...
```

Multiple services may use the same host volume.

To give a more complete example, a `docker-compose.yaml` mounting a Linux host directory into multiple docker services could e.g. look like this:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  service_1:
    image: alpine
    volumes:
      - ./shared_host_directory:/path/in/service_1
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c "echo 'A message from service 1' >> /path/in/service_1/output.log"

  service_2:
    image: alpine
    volumes:
      - ./shared_host_directory:/path/in/service_2
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c "echo 'A message from service 2' >> /path/in/service_2/output.log"
```

If you execute this example using the following commands

```sh
mkdir -p shared_host_directory  # Make sure that the shared host directory exists.
rm -rf shared_host_directory/output.log  # Make sure that the output file does not exist yet.
docker-compose up  # Execute the docker-compose.yaml file until both services terminate.
cat shared_host_directory/output.log  # Get the output of the created log file.
```

then the displayed content of `shared_host_directory/output.log` should look similar to this:

```
A message from service 1
A message from service 2
```

Note that the lines might be switched due to the race condition between the services 1 and 2.
Of course, you could also replace the relative path in the `docker-compose.yaml` by an absolute path.

Citing the docker compose file reference, https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes,

> You can mount a host path as part of a definition for a single
> service, and there is no need to define it in the top level `volumes`
> key.

Please note that the link above also contains further examples on the usage of volumes with `docker-compose`.